# WebView2: How to enable Password Autofill?

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, webview2

How can I change the "IsPasswordAutofillEnabled" Property to be "TRUE" on WebView2?

I've read the [Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2settings.ispasswordautofillenabled?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.865-prerelease) countless of times but can't actually figure out how to do it in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is an experimental feature of `Microsoft.Web.WebView2 package 1.0.865-prerelease` and only exists in this version.

If you want to use it, just add the following package references in the package reference interface:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Web.WebView2" Version="1.0.865-prerelease" />
```

[image]

Modify the attribute like this:

```
webView.CoreWebView2.Settings.IsPasswordAutofillEnabled = true;(webView is the control's name)
```

Here is the introduction document of [webview2.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms#step-1---create-a-single-window-app)